# Unable to find Lua headers with find_package in cmake

Tags: lua, cmake

I'm trying to use CMake to build generate the make file for a project of mine that uses Lua. When I run make I get this error:

```
/path/to/my/project/luaudio/luaudio.c:1:17: fatal error: lua.h: No such file or directory
```

In the CMakeLists.txt file, I have the following lines, which I thought would do it, but apparently they're not enough:

```
find_package(Lua51 REQUIRED) 
set(Luaudio_INCLUDE_DIRS ${Luaudio_SOURCE_DIR} ${Lua51_INCLUDE_DIRS} PARENT_SCOPE)
include_directories(${Luaudio_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Lua51_Include_Dirs appears to be empty (attempting to run it though the message command doesn't print anything) so I suspect that it just can't find it. Do I need to specify where to look for Lua? I was under the impression that the whole point of find_package was that it would look in a set a predefined places so that I don't need to specify where it is specifically.

(This is on an Ubuntu machine and I do have the Lua packages installed.)

Comment: Are you doing `#include "lua.h"` or `#include <lua/lua.h>`?

Comment: I am using `#include "lua.h"`. I have also tried `#include "lua/lua.h"` even though that's not what I should need to do. Neither worked. I did not try with `<>`, but if that makes a difference I will be extremely surprised.

Comment: @Alex Using `#include "lua5.1/lua.h"` worked for me after installing `lua5.1-dev`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exploring `FindLua51.cmake` from cmake 2.8 I found that it sets `LUA_INCLUDE_DIR` variable instead of `Lua51_INCLUDE_DIRS`. So cmake code should be

```
find_package(Lua51 REQUIRED) 
set(Luaudio_INCLUDE_DIRS ${Luaudio_SOURCE_DIR} ${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR} PARENT_SCOPE)
include_directories(${Luaudio_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Where is the file `FindLua51.cmake` located? I had tried at one point to look it up, but couldn't could find it in a cursory search. Edit: Success! Thank you.

Comment: On linux it will be something like `/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindLua51.cmake`

Answer (score 16):

install lua bin:

```
sudo apt-get install lua5.1
```

install lua lib:

```
sudo apt-get install lua5.1-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

for Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt install lua5.2;
sudo apt install liblua5.2-dev;
```